# Getting the position of an (real) object

Tags: python, math, python-3.4

The story: Lets say I have a robot with a distance (ultrasound?) sensor. The robot can calculate the distance from any object in front of it but it cannot know the coordinates of the object. So the robot moves a little bit to get a diffrent view angle and calculates the distance from that view knowing how far it is from the first view.

How do I get the coordinates or some kind of position of a real life object in Python 3.4 with the following input.

Distance from object at view A.
Distance from object at view B.
Distance between view A and B.

A and B are always on the same X coordinate.

Input example:

```
a = 3.5 #Distance from object at point A (in cm)

b = 7 # Disatance from object at point B (in cm)

c = 5 # Distance between A and B (in cm)
```

The output should be some coordinates or something that I can use to find out the position of an object.

**How would I calculate where the object is?** I know there is some kind of an algorithm but I don't know what it's called or how it works.

I guess this is more a math question than a programming question but I want to implement this programmatically.

Anyways the input doesn't need to be exactly this. I guess you would also need an angle or something similar so if extre input is needed just use it in the anwser.

Thanks!

(I am on Win 10, 64bit, Python 3.4)

If you know how to do this or some algorithm name but you don't know Python, please point it out or give an example of how to do it with math, and I will try to implement it in Python.

Comment: You basically have a triangle, and you know the lengths of the 3 sides.  That's not enough to get any kind of absolute position information, since you have no frame of reference.  You can, however, get the angles of the triangle using the law of cosines.

Comment: if the coordinates of the robot is know then yeah, the coordinates of the object can be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the triangle ABC with coordinates `(0,0), (b,0), (cx,cy)` (fix the origin at A for want of anywhere better to put it -- you can always shift your coordinates later).

Then you know the quantities `AC^2 = cx^2 + cy^2`, `BC^2 = (cx-b)^2 + cy^2`. These equations you can solve for `cx = (AC^2 - BC^2 + b^2)/2b` and `cy = +/- sqrt(AC^2 - cx^2)`.
Note that you don't provide enough information to deduce the sign of cy (which "side" of the x-axis your object is).

This is straightforward to code in Python.

Comment: Could you please explain this simpler? I am only 13 and English isn't my primary lanuage. Now I don't know what to do with this. I understand how it's calculated, but what are cx and cy? And which variable is supposed to be/ how do I calculate from this the end result, the object position?

Comment: cx and cy are the coordinates for the object and those are teh variables you are trying to solve for

Comment: Yes, the object's position is `(cx, cy)`. We choose `A` to be at the origin, and `B` is another fixed point (on the x-axis, the way I've written it), so `AC` is the distance from `A` to `C` and `BC` is the distance from `B` to `C`. `AB`, the distance from `A` to `B` is what I've called `b`.

Answer (score 0):

The object is in two circumferences, one with center in position 1 of the robot (known) and radius `a` (= distance from position 1 to object) and another with center in position 2 and radius `b` (= distance from position 2 to object). Then it is a matter of finding the intersection of these two circumferences. Since the circumferences will intersect in two points you still have to determine in which one of these points the object is. Therefore you will need some additional information to decide this, but I'm sure with this little help you will get started.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an ultrasonic sensor?

```
A = (-c/2, 0)
B = (+c/2, 0)
C = (tx, ty), ty >= 0
```

then

```
AC^2 = (tx+c/2)^2 + ty^2 = a^2
BC^2 = (tx-c/2)^2 + ty^2 = b^2
```

Since the answer is uniquely determined, it is only solved after.

Comment: Thx! This helped me a lot with understanding.